# automorphisms of a measurable space can be approximated by continuous measure preserving maps?

Tags: measure-theory, approximation-theory, automorphism-groups, lebesgue-measure

Suppose first that $D=[0,1]$ is equipped with the usual Lebesgue measure, and that $\varphi$ is a measure-preserving transformation $\varphi:D\to D$ that is bijective and whose inverse is also measure preserving (called automorphism).

Is it true that there exists a sequence of continuous  measure-preserving transformations $\varphi_n:D\to D$ converging in measure to $\varphi$?

Comment: If you want the continuous measure-preserving transformations to be automorphisms also, then certainly not...

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I know, I removed that condition

Comment: You probably should edit the title also. One interesting example to keep in mind is where $\phi$ is the map that takes a point $x$ and interchanges the $2n-1$st and $2n$th binary digit of $x$ for all $n$. This is an automorphism, and I believe it can be approximated by continuous mpts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, sequences of continuous piecewise linear transformations of $[0,1]$ suffice to  approximate a.e. any   measure preserving transformation of $[0,1]$ as proved [in thm 2.1 in this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume13_2/708257.pdf) (therefore in measure, by Severini-Egorov  theorem; but in fact in that proof convergence in measure is first proved).